# Error running windows phone emulator. Error 0x80131500

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have installed windows 8.1 on my macbook pro (Mavericks OS). I am trying to run a windows phone emulator on it. I am getting in the visual studio 2012 console.

```
1>------ Deploy started: Project: PhoneApp1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>Deploying C:\Users\yyyyy\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\PhoneApp1\PhoneApp1\Bin\Debug\PhoneApp1_Debug_AnyCPU.xap...
1>Connecting to Emulator 8.0 Update 3 720P...
1>Deployment of application to device failed.
1>0x80131500
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Can any please help me confirming that, do I need to update my version to Windows 8.1 pro so that I can run the Windows 8 phone emulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install Visual Studio 2012 Update 4. This will fix this issue.
[Visual Studio 2012 Update 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39305)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, too. After installing the [Visual Studio 2012 Update 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-hk/download/confirmation.aspx?id=39305), it will be all right. Maybe you could take a look at this [page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/e1fc8c2a-664b-44a1-a9c2-f1ff4aa39c2b/windows-phone-emulator-error-0x80131500?forum=wpdevelop), I got this solution there. Hope you can solve it also. Good luck.

Comment: Hello I installed update 4 as well. Still its not working.. any idea?

Comment: Are you using Win8(Not Preview)? And check whether you have enabled [Hyper-V](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj863509(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: I am using windows 8.1 pro. and Hyper-V is enabled. I checked it by going in add windows features properties. I have tried everything still not sure why it is happening..

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to it. Need to install Windows 8.1 pro or Windows 8 pro to run the emulator as Windows 8 or Windows 8.1 does not offer the Hyper V option. Found this after browsing through Microsoft web pages. We can run the Windows phone app using a device [Windows phone 8 ] registered with Microsoft on Windows 8 or 8.1.